# Consulta SQL para saber as vendas de um periodo (ano), dividindo por mes e mostrando o total de cada mes e ano

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

Trabalho como suporte tecnico em um sistema de automação,  um cliente perguntou se havia algum relatorio no sistema que mostrasse o total de vendas do ano de 2018 dividindo por mes e mostrando o total de cada mes e o total geral do ano, acontece que esse relatorio não tem no sistema então recomendei a ele  que exportasse os relatorios do total de vendas mes a mes sendo assim 12 relatorios.

tem uma função no sistema para a criação de relatorios que requer uma instrução sql para obter os resultados e mostra-los no relatorio

a tabela que armazena as vendas é a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[venda_geral](
    [venda_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [dt_contabil] [date] NOT NULL,
    [modo_venda_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [maquina_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [codigo_situacao] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [perfil_id] [int] NULL,
    [cliente_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [vl_limite] [numeric](15, 2) NULL,
    [vl_subtotal_itens] [dbo].[moeda] NULL,
    [vl_subtotal_para_desconto] [dbo].[moeda] NULL,
    [vl_subtotal_para_servico] [dbo].[moeda] NULL,
    [qtd_fechamentos] [int] NULL,
    [numero_chamada] [int] NULL,
    [operacao_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [operacao_origem_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [dt_hr_ultimo_consumo] [datetime] NULL,
    [dt_alt] [datetime] NULL,
    [obs] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [func_atendeu_id] [int] NULL,
    [codigo_ticket] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dt_hr_abertura] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [numero_venda] [int] NULL,
    [situacao]  AS (case [codigo_situacao] when 'N' then 'normal' when 'E' then 'estornada' when 'C' then 'cancelada' when 'T' then 'transferida' else 'desconhecida' end),
    [cancelado]  AS (CONVERT([bit],case [codigo_situacao] when 'N' then (0) else (1) end,(0))),
    [transferido]  AS (CONVERT([bit],case [codigo_situacao] when 'T' then (1) else (0) end,(0))),
    [ticket]  AS (case [modo_venda_id] when (1) then 'balcão ' when (2) then 'entrega ' when (3) then 'mesa ' when (4) then 'ficha ' else 'ticket ' end+[codigo_ticket]),
    [vl_consumacao] [money] NOT NULL,
    [vl_entrada] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_venda_geral] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [venda_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

por ser uma consulta dinamica acho que uma stored procedure seria mais adequado por permitir a declaração de variaveis, fiquei algumas horas tentando criar uma em que o usuario defina a data inicial ex: 01/01/2018 e data final 31/12/2018, e o relatorio apresente o seguinte resultado.

```
Periodo de 01/01/2018 até 31/12/2018
Mes       total mensal
janeiro    10000
fevereiro  11000
março      10500
... e assim por diante e no final mostre um total anual
Total anual: 1.500.000,00
```

PS.: o mais proximo que vi do resultado foi a seguinte consulta

```
SELECT 
'Ano' = YEAR(dt_contabil),
'Mes' = MONTH(dt_contabil),
'Total' =  SUM(vl_subtotal_itens)
FROM venda_geral
GROUP BY 
YEAR(dt_contabil), MONTH(dt_contabil)
```

Comment: A sua consulta já lhe dá os resultados por mês. O que mais precisa? Do total geral?

Comment: Preciso de algo que me permita definir uma data inicial e uma data final sem ter que mudar a consulta (dinamicamente como armazenar cada data em uma variavel tipo "@data_inicial e @data_final", e tambem o total de cada mes e no fim um total anual, por isso gostaria de uma stored procedure.

Comment: TENTE SELECT YEAR(dt_contabil) ANO,
       MONTH(dt_contabil) MES,
    SUM(vl_subtotal_itens) TOTAL
FROM venda_geral
WHERE YEAR(dt_contabil) = '2018'
GROUP BY CUBE (YEAR(dt_contabil),
               MONTH(dt_contabil))

Comment: @icaro alguma resposta resolveu o seu problema? Se sim, marque ela como resposta para a boa saúde dos dados do ptSO

Answer (score 1):

Icaro, ja tentou fazer dessa forma? o único detalhe aqui é que os meses que não teve venda não vai listar.

```
SELECT CASE MONTH(dt_contabil) 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Fev'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Mar'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Abr'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Mai'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Jun'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Jul'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Ago'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Set'
         WHEN 10 THEN 'Out'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Nov'
         WHEN 12 THEN 'Dez'
       END AS Periodo,
       SUM(vl_subtotal_itens) as Valor
  FROM venda_geral
 WHERE YEAR(dt_contabil) = 2018
 GROUP BY MONTH(dt_contabil)
 UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),YEAR(dt_contabil)) AS Periodo,
       SUM(vl_subtotal_itens) as Valor
  FROM venda_geral
 WHERE YEAR(dt_contabil) = 2018
 GROUP BY YEAR(dt_contabil)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Stored Procedure` abaixo segue os seguintes passos:

1. Obtém todos os anos entre duas datas e coloca em tabela temporária (`#TmpAnos`)
2. Cria uma tabela temporária onde ficarão os registos ordenados e tratados (`#TmpVendas`)
3. Para cada ano, cria os registos dos meses, número e nome, com o valor total de cada um
4. No final cria um registo com o total do ano em causa
5. Devolve uma consulta com as colunas `Ano`, `Mes` e `Valor`

Valide se serve para o que pretende:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE TotalVendasMes
        @DataInicial    DATETIME
    ,   @DataFinal      DATETIME
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @Ano        INT
    DECLARE @TotalGeral FLOAT

    CREATE TABLE #TmpVendas
    (
            Ano     INT
        ,   Mes     INT
        ,   MesStr  NVARCHAR(20)
        ,   Valor   FLOAT
    )

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, @DataInicial) AS Ano
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  Ano + 1
        FROM    CTE
        WHERE   Ano < DATEPART(YEAR, @DataFinal)
    )
    SELECT  Ano
    INTO    #TmpAnos
    FROM    CTE

    DECLARE Cur_Vendas CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  Ano
    FROM    #TmpAnos

    OPEN Cur_Vendas

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Vendas INTO @Ano

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TmpVendas
        SELECT      @Ano
                ,   MONTH(dt_contabil)
                ,   DATENAME(MONTH, dt_contabil)
                ,   SUM(vl_subtotal_itens)
        FROM        venda_geral
        WHERE       YEAR(dt_contabil) = @Ano
        GROUP BY    @Ano
                ,   MONTH(dt_contabil)
                ,   DATENAME(MONTH, dt_contabil)

        SET @TotalGeral =   ISNULL((
                                SELECT  SUM(Valor)
                                FROM    #TmpVendas
                                WHERE   Ano = @Ano
                            ), 0)

        INSERT INTO #TmpVendas
        SELECT      @Ano
                ,   13
                ,   'Total anual (' + CAST(@Ano AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ')'
                ,   @TotalGeral

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Vendas INTO @Ano
    END

    CLOSE Cur_Vendas
    DEALLOCATE Cur_Vendas

    SELECT      Ano
            ,   MesStr
            ,   Valor
    FROM        #TmpVendas
    ORDER BY    Ano
            ,   Mes
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai mais uma opção de SQL. Não sei se você precisa o resultado em linhas ou colunas.

#### Funcionamento

Separei os meses, com `case` assim cada coluna fica um mês, e no final criei a coluna do ano. Da forma que implementei, se o mês não tiver venda, ele será listado no SQL.

#### SQL

```
select 
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 1 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes01,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 2 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes02,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 3 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes03,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 4 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes04,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 5 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes05,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 6 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes06,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 7 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes07,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 8 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes08,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 9 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes09,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 10 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes10,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 11 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes11,
  sum(case when MONTH(dt_contabil) = 12 then vl_subtotal_itens else 0 end) Mes12,
  sum(vl_subtotal_itens) as ValorAno
from 
  venda_geral
where
  dt_contabil between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
```

#### Resultado

```
| Mes01 | Mes02 | Mes03 | Mes04 | Mes05 |  Mes06 | Mes07 | Mes08 | Mes09 | Mes10 | Mes11 |   Mes12 | ValorAno |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|--------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|---------|----------|
|  50.5 |   191 | 105.5 |  10.5 |     0 | 105.99 |   5.5 | 105.5 |   0.5 |  17.5 |   1.5 | 12501.5 | 13095.49 |
```

A implementação do SQL está aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd77fb/1

Observação: Somente coloquei no exemplo as colunas que você queria no resultado, para facilitar a resposta.